How to create a minimize button?
index.js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    resizable: false,
    frame: false,
    icon: path.join(__dirname, 'icon.png'),
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      // devTools: false,
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
    },
  });

script
 const minimizeButton = document.getElementById('minimize');
    const closeButton = document.getElementById('close');

    minimizeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      window.hide();
    });

    closeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      window.close();
    });

window.close(); works fine, but when calling window.hide(); it throws TypeError: window.hide is not a function. What to do?
on
nodeIntegration: true,
contextIsolation: false,

